# How do I look ahead in searches Elastic Co

Tags: javascript, dart, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to add a search function for users in my app. When I type the word "Josh" in the search bar people with the name "Joshua" do not show up. I have type the full name "Joshua". How can I add this look-ahead functionality?

Here is my current query:

```
"bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "fields": [
                "first",
                "first.edge",
                "last",
                "last.edge",
                "title",
                "title.edge"
              ],
              "query": search,
              "fuzziness": 1,
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is using ngram.

```
PUT ngram_custom_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "3_5_grams" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "3_5_grams": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST ngram_custom_example/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name":"josh"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"joshua"}

GET ngram_custom_example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "fields": [
                "name"
              ],
              "query": "josh"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  }
}
```